# Powershell - copying or adding to a Datatable?

Tags: t-sql, powershell, datatable

I'm using Chad Miller & Hey Scripting Guy's functions [invoke-sqlcmd2](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/7985b7ef-ed89-4dfd-b02a-433cc4e30894/) and [write-datatable](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/2fdeaf8d-b164-411c-9483-99413d6053ae/) to save the results of a query to a datatable, then write it into a SQL table.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
$dt = invoke-sqlcmd2 -serverinstance $_.server -query "exec master.dbo.sp_who" -As 'Datatable' 
write-datatable -serverinstance "myserverhere" -DATABASE "dbainfo" -tablename "who_sp_results" -DATA $dt
```

I want to add a field to the datatable - I'm running an SP I can't modify, and want to add the servername.  I'm running it in parallel, so I can't use a staging table, I have to either modify the existing datatable or move it to a new datatable.

1. How do I copy/alter a datatable to get the additional column and set it to another variable?
2. If we use a second datatable, since I'm looping, how do I "truncate"
   it or clear it out prior to the next run within the foreach loop?

UPDATE: added one row from $dt | select-object * , and $dt | get-member

```
spid       : 1
ecid       : 0
status     : background                    
loginame   : sa
hostname   :                                                                                                                           

blk        : 0    
dbname     : 
cmd        : RESOURCE MONITOR
request_id : 0
RowError   : 
RowState   : Unchanged
Table      : {sa, sa, sa, sa...}
ItemArray  : {1, 0, background                    , sa...}
HasErrors  : False
```

Here's the results from $dt | get-member :

TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

```
Name              MemberType            Definition                                                                                     
----              ----------            ----------                                                                                     
AcceptChanges     Method                System.Void AcceptChanges()                                                                    
BeginEdit         Method                System.Void BeginEdit()                                                                        
CancelEdit        Method                System.Void CancelEdit()                                                                       
ClearErrors       Method                System.Void ClearErrors()                                                                      
Delete            Method                System.Void Delete()                                                                           
EndEdit           Method                System.Void EndEdit()                                                                          
Equals            Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                 
GetChildRows      Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(...
GetColumnError    Method                string GetColumnError(int columnIndex), string GetColumnError(string columnName), string Get...
GetColumnsInError Method                System.Data.DataColumn[] GetColumnsInError()                                                   
GetHashCode       Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                              
GetParentRow      Method                System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(stri...
GetParentRows     Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRow...
GetType           Method                type GetType()                                                                                 
HasVersion        Method                bool HasVersion(System.Data.DataRowVersion version)                                            
IsNull            Method                bool IsNull(int columnIndex), bool IsNull(string columnName), bool IsNull(System.Data.DataCo...
RejectChanges     Method                System.Void RejectChanges()                                                                    
SetAdded          Method                System.Void SetAdded()                                                                         
SetColumnError    Method                System.Void SetColumnError(int columnIndex, string error), System.Void SetColumnError(string...
SetModified       Method                System.Void SetModified()                                                                      
SetParentRow      Method                System.Void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow parentRow), System.Void SetParentRow(System.Dat...
ToString          Method                string ToString()                                                                              
Item              ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int columnIndex) {get;set;}, System.Object Item(string columnName) {get;s...
blk               Property              System.String blk {get;set;}                                                                   
cmd               Property              System.String cmd {get;set;}                                                                   
dbname            Property              System.String dbname {get;set;}                                                                
ecid              Property              System.Int16 ecid {get;set;}                                                                   
hostname          Property              System.String hostname {get;set;}                                                              
loginame          Property              System.String loginame {get;set;}                                                              
request_id        Property              System.Int32 request_id {get;set;}                                                             
spid              Property              System.Int16 spid {get;set;}                                                                   
status            Property              System.String status {get;set;}
```

Comment: if you provide `$dt | get-member` then maybe someone without an sql server can try to help too :-)

Comment: @Graimer - added, let me know what else you need! Thanks.

Comment: perfect. seems Chad got a solution for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use add-member as this won't add a type of datacolumn. Instead do the following:

```
$Col =  new-object Data.DataColumn
$Col.ColumnName = "ServerName"
$dt.Columns.Add($col)
$dt | %{$_.ServerName = "myserverName"}
```

BTW if you use get-member with inputobject parameter you'll see the columns and add method:

**gm -inputobject $dt**

This is different than
**$dt | gm** which returns properties and methods of datarows. The first one doesn't unroll.

Comment: yes, but getting a normal `gm` will let people like me who haven't used datatables or the scripts before know what kind of objects are inside the table(ex. `System.Data.Data* ` objects and not customobj). :)

Comment: also, you can simplify this to: `$dt.Columns.Add("ServerName"); $dt | %{$_.ServerName = "myserverName"}`

Comment: @Graimer +1 on your comment to simplify. The "gm -input $var" vs. "$var | gm" is something that I found confusing at first so I thought I'd point it out here and certainly makes a difference in DataTable vs. DataRows

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Add-Member`

Comment: Tried, no dice.  `$dt | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -value 'myservername'` doesn't work, nor does `, $dt | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -value 'myservername'`, nor does `$dt | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -value $_.server` ($_.server has the servername at that point)

Comment: When you say doesn't work, was there an error or it just didn't do anything?

Comment: I assume you used `Get-Member` to see if it was added or not. The `Format-` class of functions might not show it even if it is there.

Comment: Nope - powershell newbie, I thought the select-object would show it all.  However, I ran the get-member before and after, and the two are identical.